# How to display records in form using DoCmd.OpenForm?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Apologies for the newb question, but I am having a really hard time opening a form using `DoCmd.OpenForm` and getting it to display some results. Here's what I have so far:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Report", acFormDS, , , acFormReadOnly
Forms!Report.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MyReport"
```

This results in a new form being launched, however, all of the rows and columns are blank. It is returning the correct amount of rows that I am expecting, however, they are all empty. I believe I need to somehow 'bind' a subform to the "Report" form, but I'm not exactly sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that **dbo.MyReport** is a linked table. Access doesn't allow periods in it's object names. Usually, when linking, Access will change the periods to underscores. So, more than likely your table name within Access is **dbo_MyReport**.